# AngularJS not loading in outside library (CodeMirror) correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use CodeMirror in my AngularJS application. I included the codemirror .css and .js files by downloading the lib folder and linking them in my index.html of my angular project. I then added a script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("query_box"), {
    mode: "sql",
    styleActiveLine: true,
    lineNumbers:true,
    lineWrapping: true
  }); 
});
```

to turn my textarea into a syntax-highlighting code editor.

The markup for the textarea that I want to CodeMirror-ify looks like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="query_box" class="form-control" id="query_box" name="query_box"></textarea>
```

Seems simple enough.

However, when the page loads, I get an unstyled textarea and this error message in my JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null codemirror.js:4935
  CodeMirror.fromTextArea codemirror.js:4935
  (anonymous function) script.js:10
  fire jquery.js:3119
  self.fireWith jquery.js:3231
  jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:3443
  completed
```

When I type

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("query_box"))
```

directly into my JS console, it does work without errors. Any reason why jquery isn't running the appropriate javascript automatically?

Comment: Since you're using jquery why not use `$('#query_box')`, and rather than run the function, try and `console.log( $('#query_box') )` and see if it returns a value. I expect that it doesn't.

Comment: I get this output from that console.log: [context: document, selector: "#query_box", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…]
context: document
selector: "#query_box"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: Yup, it's not finding element. Are you dynamically adding the div? Are you sure, you're `$(document).on('ready')` function is working?

Comment: the $(document).on('ready') code is running. The #query_box is added by angular

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a DOM element before it's been added. You could nest your code inside an angular event that fires once the elements have been added: `$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() { }`